The GET method is not supported for route (to delete). Supported methods: DELETE. (I'm using Post & Delete)
I have implemented a modal to delete objects in my project, the problem is that when I click delete, it tells me that I am using a get method even though I use a post/delete method.
<form id="delete-form-' + dataResult.data[i].id + '" action="/inventario/' + dataResult.data[i].id + '" method="POST" class="d-inline">
    @csrf
    @method("DELETE")
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>+
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" "style="padding-left: 6px">
        Aceptar
    </button>
    </div>
</form>

The JS Code to manage the form:
$(document).on('submit', 'form\[id^="delete-form-"\]', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

console.log('Entrado al submit del form de eliminar disco');
var form = $(this);

var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(), 
        success: function(data) {
            form.closest('tr').remove();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Error al eliminar disco',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            });
        }
    });
});

And routes and destroy method:
Route::get('/inventario',[InventarioController::class,'index'])->middleware('auth'); 
Route::delete('/inventario/{id}', [InventarioController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth');
 Route::get('/inventario/nuevo',[InventarioController::class,'create'])->middleware('auth'); 
Route::post('/inventario/nuevo',[InventarioController::class,'store'])->middleware('auth'); 
Route::get('/inventario/editar/{id}',[InventarioController::class,'edit'])->middleware('auth');


public function destroy(Inventario $inventario)
{
$imagenInventario = ImagenInventario::findOrFail($inventario-\>id);
$imagenInventario-\>delete();

        $inventario->delete();
    
        return redirect()->back();
    }

I tried to modify the web routes, to force trough JS the send via DELETE and nothing works, always is GET:


Check if your action url is correct and if the ID properly placed in url.

I have checked, as you can see in the image, if I enter directly the path to delete with any ID, it says that it supports get, even though the path is Delete. Thanks for your answer!

The problem is not at the submitting of the form but in the fact that you visit the link http://localhost:8000/inventario/9 in the browser, because every call from the browser link bar is a GET request, to test DELETE or POST request you have to use tools like Postman or Insomnia Rest

@RaúlGarcía why are you not using the DELETE method inside de ajax request?

@Maraboc my bad, I missexplain the error, when i tried to call to the method trough the modal/js, i received error 404, if I press "Open in new tab" the error describes as the title of the picture, I Know that the browser cant do post or delete, but my ajax method should... Thanks for your options!

@GiulianoArnhold I tried too, post and delete end in the same way.

In the end I chose to create my elimination method as a bypass and do soft deletions, it is not what I needed, but it is a solution after all...
